# AJAX POST request in Spring-MVC does not works

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC and I have stuck at how to send a simple string value from client using AJAX and print it at JAVA server (controller). I have written below code for doing this. But when I click button to send string, `error....` response is popped-up in my browser and the browser console displays `POST http://localhost:8090/addUser 404 ()`. It has been a day since I am trying to solve this issue. Can someone please tell what can be the problem? Or please tell a working alternative solution for sending data from client using AJAX and printing/saving it on JAVA server (Spring-MVC).

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public JSONArray addUser(@ModelAttribute("UserTest") JSONArray name) {
        System.out.println(name.toString());
        return name;
    }
}
```

**AJAX Request:**

```
<script>
    function addUser() {
        var json = '{"uname":"John", "Age":42}';
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            $.ajax({
                    url : "/addUser",
                    data : obj,
                    type : "POST",
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success : function(response) {
                             alert( response );
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert("error...."); //this is being popped-up in my browser     
                    }
            });
       }
</script>
```

Comment: if you ara using jsp for view purpose change url to `url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addUser'`

Answer (score 0):

> POST `http://localhost:8090/addUser` 404 ()

Your request is going to `http://localhost:8090/addUser`, which is not correct. Your request url should have your application and included.

```
http://localhost:8090/<app_name>/addUser
```

AFAIK, your request url should have application name included. Now, to achieve this, you are suppose to change your ajax `url`

```
 url : "/<app_name>/addUser"
```

Comment: now getting this error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: @Agha were you able to access this page manually ? if yes, then what is the url ?. Also, could share your web.xml and spring xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the ajax call is not correct. It should be like

Url:YourApplicationContextPath/ControllerName/addUser